# Java 8 lambda Collectors.groupingBy with map in Collector.toList()

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have implemented the following example:

```
Map<String, List<Event>> map = events.getItems().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getStatus, Collectors.toList()));
```

How can I get an output of `Map<String, List<EventDto>> map` instead?

An `EventDto` can be obtained by executing an external method which converts an `Event` to an `EventDto`. For example - `this::convertFromEventToEventDto`.

Comment: What is `EventDto` and how is it related to the elements of your Stream?

Comment: @eran I should use external function to convert `Event` to `EventDto`. I think in explanation can be used any name if you with, or for example `this::convertFromEventToEventDto`

Comment: Does `EventDto` have a status?

Comment: I tried this idea also, but it is different story because of some restrictions and I should not change `EventDto`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need a `mapping` `Collector` to map the `Event` elements to `EventDto` elements :

```
Map<String, List<EventDto>> map = 
    events.getItems()
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getStatus, 
                                         Collectors.mapping(this::convertFromEventToEventDto,
                                                            Collectors.toList())));
```